# User model trying to validate password presence on an update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple user account update form in which I am trying to update the logged in user's account information. But when I try to do a user.update_attribute, it fails complaining that password is empty, even though my validation for password presence says `:on => :create`

Why is this happening? **I am not using devise/authlogic or any other auth gem**

My User model looks like this (it has the usual suspects password_hash/salt as columns):

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create, :unless => :provider?
```

The UsersController has the following update method:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes params[:user]

  # this prints error hash, see output below
  logger.error @user.errors.inspect 

  # other rendering code
  flash[:notice] = 'Saved OK'
  render :action => :edit
end
```

The @user.errors.inspect output after calling @user.update_attributes -

```
#<OrderedHash {:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}>
```

Comment: Are you using any gems such as Devise or Authlogic?

Comment: Try validates_presence_of :password, :unless => "authentications.present?"

Comment: not using any devise/authlogic or any other auth gem

Comment: The only validation you show us in the code is for presence, and yet the error is for length.  Where is the length validation and is it also on `:create`?

Comment: yea that was the problem, was missing :create for length validation. Thanks. Also is there a way to check if a model was saved successfully in the DB after a create/update??

Comment: Most methods that commit changes to a record return true or false respective to success or failure, `update_attributes` included.